# Return the last digit of a number

Tags: java, beginner

```
public static int lastDigit(int a) {
    a = a % 10;
    if (a <= 0){
    a *= -1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

This is my solution. The course hasn't taught if else yet, so I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without the if else.

```
public static int lastDigit(int a) {
a = a % 10;
return a;
}
```

The problem with this is that it will not print the last digit of a negative number as a positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Math.abs()`

```
 public static int lastDigit(int x) {
      return Math.abs(x % 10);
 }
```

Comment: Well I feel somewhat stupid. Thanks though

Comment: Figured courses should be teaching `if-else` before `static` methods invocation... oh wells.

Comment: I make all methods static just to avoid problems.